# I can't see in the dash the filter function

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-dash

The dash in Ubuntu 11.10 should display on the right side a filter function which I can't see. I am using a netbook with the usual 10" screen with a 1024x600 resolution. Any idea how to reduce the icon size to be able to see the filter function area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter function only works on the *'Search Applications'  'Search Files & Folders and 'Search Music Collection'*

These are accessed on the bottom of the open Dash via the icons.